# Problem : Behavioral trigger abandon basket

Tags: marketing-cloud, code, einstein-recommendations, behavioral-triggers

I try to set up the behavioral trigger on the abandoned basket.
I created the product catalog with the required fields including the product_code which seems important. I made sure that avaibility on the catalog is on YES.
I added the following code on the site that is managed on GTM.

```
<script type="text/gtmscript" data-gtmsrc="https://MID.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js">
</script>
<script type="text/gtmscript">
    _etmc.push(["setOrgId",
        "MID"
    ]);
    _etmc.push(["setUserId",
        "126"
    ]);
    _etmc.push(["trackCart",
                            {"cart":[
                                          {
                                          "item": "PRPECOM001885",
                                          "quantity": "2",
                                          "price": "309.00",
                                          "unique_id": "xx6"
                                          },
                                          {
                                          "item": "6598-2",
                                          "quantity": "3",
                                          "price": "1.0",
                                          "unique_id": "xx2"
                                          },
                                          {
                                          "item": "testabsoludemo5",
                                          "quantity": "1",
                                          "price": "50.00",
                                          "unique_id": "xx5"
                                          }
                            ]}
              ]);
</script>
```

And SFMC is not feed by the data. I made a ticket with the support SFMC. The support tells me that my code seems to be incorrect. But I don't understand how. And they can't help me anymore.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the payload and url when this code fires?

Comment: Payload should look like this:
`payload: {"cart":[{"item":"PRPECOM001885","quantity":"2","price":"309.00","unique_id": "xx6"},{"item":"000000000000088487","quantity":"1","price": "1.0","unique_id": "xx2"},{"item":"testabsoludemo5","quantity":"1","price":"50.00","unique_id": "xx5"],,"url":"https://www.whatever.com","user_info":{"email":"126"}}`

Comment: Maybe a Typo but you do not make the setUserCall correct. It needs to be this one   `_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID"}]);` for you this would be `_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "126"}]);` when you have a subscriber-key 126. If this is your mistake i will make an answer out of this one :)

Comment: at the end it was missing "email" in the setuserID tag. Thanks johannes for having found :-) and Thanks Easy for having tried :-)